# Laravel "with" changes variable case to snake case

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

In my Laravel app, I have A model that defines a relationship like:

```
public function vitalCategories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Models\Diagonals\VitalLabelCategory',
        'vitalLabelCategoryMap',
        'vitalLabelId',
        'vitalLabelCategoryId');
}
```

When I query a record like below, I expect the relation to be available with the variable name `vitalCategories`

```
$vitalLabel = VitalLabel::where('label', 'confirmation')->with(['subscribers','vitalCategories','vitals'])->first();
return json_encode($vitalLabel);
```

However, the above query produces the relation with the variable name 'vital_categories' like this:

[image]

**How can I make laravel stop changing the case of my variable for the relation to snake case?**

Just for grins, I also tried:

```
$vitalLabel = VitalLabel::where('label', 'confirmation')->with(['subscribers','vitalCategories','vitals'])->first();
$vitalLabel->load('vitalCategories');
$vitalLabel->vitalCategories = $vitalLabel->vitalCategories() ;
return json_encode($vitalLabel);
```

which failed to see the related models:

[image]

so then I tried:

```
$vitalLabel = VitalLabel::where('label', 'confirmation')->with(['subscribers','vitalCategories','vitals'])->first();
$vitalLabel->load('vitalCategories');
$vitalLabel->vitalCategories = $vitalLabel->vital_categories;
return json_encode($vitalLabel);
```

which also failed to see the related models:

[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Laravel automatically converts the names of relationships from `camelCase` to `snake_case` when the model is converted to an array (`toArray()`) or json (`toJson()`).

So, the attribute on the model is actually `vitalCategories`, but when you dump it out as json, it will print as `vital_categories`.

If you would like to turn this off, you can set the `$snakeAttributes` property on your model to false.

```
public static $snakeAttributes = false;
```

Comment: It seems it's actually `static $snakeAttributes = false;`  (static vs protected) but you nailed it, thank you!

Comment: @DelightedD0D Yeah, and it's `public`, too. Sorry, I was going more from memory than looking at the actual code. Silly me. I've updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Flawless answer

Comment: Also, since the property is public, you can set it right before you get the array, or anywhere for that matter. The key is that it's very easy to forget you don't need this during the `load()` method, rather during the `toArray()` method.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of goofy behavior that will make me leave a framework like laravel. Come on Laravel, you can do better.