# Laravel Eloquent eager Loading and Retrieving Values From the Array

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Using Laravel's Eloquent and eager loading how would one retrieve the values in the built_load_cost array and th built_load_revenue array?

```

```
  array:11 [▼
  "id" => 5
  "created_at" => "2018-03-24 00:19:52"
  "updated_at" => "2018-03-24 00:20:14"
  "load_number" => 1
  "dispatcher_id" => 3
  "carrier_id" => 826097731
  "customer_id" => 1
  "ip" => "127.0.0.1"
  "deleted_at" => null
  "built_load_cost" => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "created_at" => "2018-03-26 19:59:34"
    "updated_at" => "2018-03-26 19:59:34"
    "line_haul" => "100.00"
    "extra_pickups" => "0.00"
    "built_load_id" => 5
  ]
  "built_load_revenue" => array:6 [▼
    "id" => 4
    "created_at" => "2018-03-26 19:59:43"
    "updated_at" => "2018-03-26 19:59:43"
    "line_haul" => "90.00"
    "extra_pickups" => "0.00"
    "built_load_id" => 5
  ]
]
```

```

Comment: Hmm, the same way as with any other array. `$arr[index][prop]` in your case. Maybe I don't understand the question.

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought. Except it returns null. I have this query: $load = BuiltLoad::with('builtLoadCost')->with('builtLoadRevenue')->where('dispatcher_id', '=', $dispatcher_id)->where('id', '=', $id)->first();
        then I use this : $line_haul = $load['built_load_revenue']['line_haul']; ... which returns null. Cannot figure out why I am getting null.I should be getting 90

Comment: How are you retrieving the data that you're getting null?

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo  I able to to retrieve the values for load-number and customer_id and all values for the main array, just not from the 2 arrays mentioned in my initial question

Comment: Post the code that you use to retrieve that data that gives you null

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo                                                                              
  $load = BuiltLoad::with('builtLoadCost')->with('builtLoadRevenue')->where('dispatcher_id', '=', $dispatcher_id)->where('id', '=', $id)->first();

Comment: Not the code that loads data.but the code that you later use to get build_load_cost from the array. And how do you convert the result in $load into array?

Comment: Ahh so sorry, Should also be in my comment above. Here  it is.... $line_haul_revenue = $load['built_load_revenue']['line_haul'];   and $line_haul_cost = $load['built_load_cost']['line_haul'];     Thank you much,

Answer (score 0):

When accessing value through eloquent model, use `camelCase`, with first lower case letter:

```
$load->builtLoadCost->line_haul
$load['builtLoadCost']['line_haul']
```

If the eloquent model is converted to array, use `snake_case` to access relations:

```
$load->toArray()['built_load_revenue']['line_haul']
```

See also: [Laravel “with” changes variable case to snake case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44793812/laravel-with-changes-variable-case-to-snake-case)

Comment: Thank you.  This $load->toArray()['built_load_revenue']['line_haul'] worked. Still not sure why my original code does not and your code works. i thought eloquent model I used was returning an array.

Comment: eloquent model is not an array, but you can use it as an array because of overloading, `->toArray()` is used to serialize an eloquent model to an array