# Why Eloquent changes column name?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

My book table's primary key is called ISBN.

[image: book table's pk]

But when I try to update others columns using the ISBN I get the following error:

[image: ISBN]

I can fix it changing the eloquent query, but I want to know why this mistake appears.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you please share your `Book` class ?

Comment: In your `BookModel` write this line if you haven't written. `protected $primaryKey = 'ISBN';`

Comment: Another point is Laravel uses camelCase means when you write a function or id like `ISBN` in capital letters laravel will assume it `i_s_b_n`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Laravel automatically converts the names of relationships from camelCase to snake_case when the model is converted to an array (toArray()) or json (toJson()).

to avoid this changes write this line in your model:

```
public static $snakeAttributes = false;
```

see:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44794070/10573560

Comment: It doesn't work. I'm still having the same error. I tried to write the line you give me and the primary key in the model.

Comment: please write the query witch made the error in your question

Comment: sorry to be late, after long research, it was obvious that it's laravel convention, so tweak it would take some effort,

Comment: you had to make you own model class, like in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33710995/10573560